# dbt docs does not detect column types in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, dbt, codegen

Whenever I run `dbt docs generate` I am able to successfully generate the default dbt documentation. However, I expect dbt to automatically detect and fill out the column type:

[image]

I this a problem of the `dbt-sqlserver` adapter I am using? Is one of the sub-macros needed such as `get_columns_in_relation` not implemented there?

The package `codegen` that should also be able to generate the "sources yml" does not work either. I assume these two issues are connected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, I don't think I changed anything here:
[image]

[image]